# Form's submit does not work when I load a page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm working on this system, and the guy who wrote it uses JQuery to submit the form like this:

```
$(".btnFinalizaEnvioPedido").click(function() {
    $("#modalAvisoEnviaPedido").modal("hide");
    $("#myModalCarregando").modal('show');
    $("form[name=pedido]").submit();
});
```

And this is his form:

```
<form class="jqtransform" method="post" name="pedido" id="form-pedido">
```

This page wherein the form lies works perfectly when accessed by itself, but I find this method ugly so I'm loading the whole page with JQuery in the previous one, but when I do it, the whole form stops working.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".icon_sisconbr-icons-pedidos").click(function () {
            $("body").load("../pedido/novo.php");
        });
        $(".btnFinalizaEnvioPedido").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../pedido/acoes.php",
                success: function (result) {
                    ...     
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't know how to make that submit work with AJAX. The method is POST (Not GET). Why the submit works when I actually ENTER the page with a `<a>` / link, and does not work when I load the whole page with JQuery's load??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `load` the contents of the page are created after `document.ready` has already fired, so your click event is attached when the button doesn't exist on the page.

Instead of `.click` you can use `.on` to attach to the document itself and specify the element to listen to events on.

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnFinalizaEnvioPedido", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../pedido/acoes.php",
        success: function (result) {
            ...     
        }
    });
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more info

Answer (score 1):

Because you must load body before bind to elements.
In your scenario try to bind click for ajax event after `$('body').load(/***/)` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Your manner doesn't post the form data, if you want to use your code you must pass the form inputs in data string:
    $(".btnFinalizaEnvioPedido").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: 'name='+('#name_txt').val()+'&address='+.       ('#address_txt').val(),
    url: "./pedido/acoes.php",
    success: function (result) {
    ...
    }
            });
        });